# Clion Files are greyed out

Tags: c, clion, assign

Now the thing is that all other files Qa,Qb,Qc,Qd except Qe are greyed out. Whats the reason for this? What I have to do to be able to run Qa for instance I gotta delete the set(SOURCE_FILES Q_.c) of all others. How can I make them not greyed out if that makes sense.
Thanks

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(Assignment)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

set(SOURCE_FILES Qa.c)
set(SOURCE_FILES Qb.c)
set(SOURCE_FILES Qc.c)
set(SOURCE_FILES Qd.c)
set(SOURCE_FILES Qe.c)


add_executable(Assignment ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Comment: Is it related to [Project can be compiled correctly, but highlighting, completion, refactorings, etc. in CLion are not working. CLion fails to find some of my classes. What to do?](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207253145-Project-can-be-compiled-correctly-but-highlighting-completion-refactorings-etc-in-CLion-are-not-working-CLion-fails-to-find-some-of-my-classes-What-to-do-)

Comment: Yes I saw that but didnt actually understand it.

Comment: The [blog](http://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2015/12/mark-dir-as/) link at the bottom mentions there are three options "Directories under your control: ‘Mark Directory As’", sounds like you want to include those files as part of your project, maybe try using the "Mark directory as Project sources and headers:" (BTW, I'm just offering this "suggestion", I have no experience or knowledge of `clion`)

Answer (score 2):

Don't redefine `SOURCE_FILES` constantly (ie overwrite the old value). Either append to it, or add all files in the same assignment.

I.e.:

```
set(SOURCE_FILES
    Qa.c
    Qb.c
    Qd.c
    Qe.c
)
```

Comment: How exactly if I may ask?

Comment: Added an example of the simplest way.